# Can I use other prefixes other than 'is' in WCMUsePojo boolean getters?

Tags: aem, pojo, sightly, htl

I've seen conventions in Java pojos that use *can*, *has*, and *should* instead of the usual *is*. However, in AEM 6.1 we have `WCMUsePojo` right? *is* works for sure, and I've tried *has* but hasn't worked. Is this a bug or `WCMUsePojo` never really intended other getter prefixes for booleans other than *is*?

Comment: afaik sightly compiler supports only "is" and "get" prefixes.

Comment: However, you can call the full method name. Say your method is ‘hasTitle’, in your HTL expression you can use ‘hasTitle’

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

The `Use` api looks at a Pojo from the perspective of a Java Bean.

http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/7224-javabeans-1.01-fr-spec-oth-JSpec/

For boolean values the convention is that the value be prefixed with an 'is' or a 'get' prefix. Using the prefix "has" has never been a part of the JavaBean specification. However that doesn't mean that the Use API shouldn't do that. Contextually "has" makes more sense sometimes. So you may be able to open a request or inquire about having that added to the api support. The maintainers of HTL are the committers to the Apache Sling project

https://sling.apache.org/

And if you are interested the source code for HTL is here
https://github.com/apache/sling-org-apache-sling-scripting-sightly

Comment: I see. I assumed that the other prefixes were part of the standard. Apparently, it _is_ just 'is' and nothing else. That might be a good suggestion for the HTL team. Thank you for clarifying!!